# Fetch new scrape information - php, facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I had different cat images and i am loading different og:image when page loads everytime.

```
<meta property="og:image"   content="http://example.com/images/<?php echo $randomCatImage; ?>">
```

Different images are loading as expected for og:image tag, when i share the link or post the link on facebook (example.com/about-cats) facebook cache showing same preview/image. I want to show random cat image everytime.

```
(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)
```

When fetch new information using above url, the facebook cache is getting updated and when i share or type (example.com/about-cats) link on facebook, I get new preview with new image...

My question is how to update the facebook cache (or scrape information) automatically using php ?

Comment: Facebook caches for a reason, so that its not drawing live data all the time. Trying to circumvent that will be difficult.

Comment: og tags are not meant to be used for random images. after a while, data gets locked for a specific url.

Comment: once check this website www.fbbb.co. When we type or post this link on facebook. Everytime on random preview  is generating.

Comment: i did not say it´s not possible, but it´s a very bad idea and it will probably not work in the long run.

Comment: Yes i understood but i just want to try... can you let me know or guide me how to do it ?